# Django website serving data to mobile app

Tags: django, web-services, api

I am currently trying to figure out he best practice in order to design my web services between a django administrated database (+ images) and a mobile app. My main concern is how to separate a bulk update (send every data in the database and all the files on the server) and a lighter, smaller update with only the new and / or modified objects (images or data.)

I have had access to a working code-base using a cronjob and states for each data field (new, modified, up to date) to generate either a reference data file or an update file. I find it to be very redundant and somewhat unelegant, in contradiction with the DRY spirit of Django (there are tons of lines of code, making it nearly unmaintainable.))

I find it very surprising that this aspect is almost un-documented, since web traffic is a crucial matter in mobile developpment.. Fetching everytime all the data served quickly becomes unsustainable as the database grows..

I would be very grateful for any lead or advice you could give me :-) Thx in advance !

Comment: What was your question again?

Comment: I'm looking for a better way to manage and serve updates to my mobile app, and avoiding to force a full update using way too much traffic. I have seen an ugly way to do so, which I described, and I'm wondering if there isn't any cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a last_modified DateTimeField in your table, and in your user's profile a last_synchronized DateTimeField. When the mobile app wants to synchronize, send the data which was modified after the last synchronization run, and update the last_synchronized field in the user's profile.